# Contar valores em uma tabela MSAccess

Tags: c#, microsoft-access, visual-studio-2012

Estou criando minha primeira aplicação e gostaria de saber como conto valores de uma tabela em MSAccess com as seguintes condições:

- "solicitante" e "Status" devem conter valores específicos;
- Se contiver os dados `solicitante = solicitante1` e `status = aberto`, contar todos os valores que satisfaçam essa condição.

Tentei algo assim mas não consigo retornar valores. Tentei usar o `COUNT` também.

Se alguém puder me dar uma luz em como fazer o teste de condição e armazenar os valores em uma variável. Agradeço desde já.

```
string query7 =  " SELECT (Status_Solicitante)  from Cartoes where Status_Solicitante='"+"Aberto" + Solic+"'";
command7.CommandText = query7;
OleDbDataReader reader7 = command7.ExecuteReader();
while (reader7 .Read())
{
    label11.Text =  reader7.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Onde você seleciona o `Status`?

Comment: como eu não sabia como avaliar os dois campos coloquei um campo onde os dois campos são unidos Status_Solicitante onde neste campo quando o usuario salvar ele será preenchido com a palavra AbertoSolicitante. o que eu preciso é contar este campo.

Comment: [Pode por favor colocar sua tabela aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: no campo da tabela chamado Status = Aberto, Solicitante = Solicitante1,Status_Solicitante = AbertoSolicitante1.

Comment: Tu queres só contar quantos registros na tabela atendem a tua condição, certo?

Comment: exatamente, Preciso saber quantos registros foram abertos por um determinado solicitante e com status de aberto.